# Curling an elasticsearch instance in a VM from the host

Tags: curl, networking, elasticsearch, centos, virtualbox

So I installed CentOs in a VM and then elastic search, I set up it's network as bridge.

Elasticsearch 1.7.3 is of course running.

I can SSH to it without issue however curl is not working

```
curl '163.113.183.229:9200/_cat/indices?v'
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

What can I look at to identify the problem?
Thanks

## EDIT

CentOs 7 block the port 80 which I opened but no change :

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch version 2.0 and later only answers requests from localhost by default.

To connect from other machines, edit `elasticsearch.yml` and add:

```
network.host: ["_local_", "_non_loopback_"]
```

Comment: Oops, should have precised, I'm using ES 1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

So Centos7 is using firewalld and some port/protocol need to be opened/allowed,
this will allow you to curl you ES instance :

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9200/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```

In addition if using a ES>= 2.0.0 you should read Daphna Shezaf awnser

Answer (score 0):

Just want to note that as of Elasticsearch version 6, `_non_loopback_` is not a valid parameter for `network.host`. They can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values). I needed to use `_site_` in my case to allow access from outside my VM.